# Ionic: How to set a header on multiple pages?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, module, header, ng-modules

I've created a new app using Ionic with 3 components, Home, Header and Footer. 
I'm trying to use Header and Footer on multiple pages (for now only on Home page), by making a reference to them.

I've tried to reference the Header into the Home.page.html but I does not work.

```
<app-header></app-header>

<ion-content>
    <div class="ion-padding">
        The world is your oyster.
        <p>If you get lost, the <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/">docs</a> will be your guide.</p>
    </div>
.
.
.
```

I'm getting the error: 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected directive 'HeaderPage' imported by the module 'HomePageModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
Error: Unexpected directive 'HeaderPage' imported by the module 'HomePageModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Besides the error, I'm not even sure that the Header is called using `<app-header></app-header>`

For the modules I have the following codes:

Home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
// import { MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatTabsModule, MatChipsModule, MatIconModule, MatToolbarModule, MatDatepickerModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatNativeDateModule } from "@angular/material";

import { HomePage } from './home.page';
// import { FooterPage } from '../footer/footer.page';
import { HeaderPage } from '../header/header.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HeaderPage,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

header.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HeaderPage } from './header.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HeaderPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [HeaderPage],
  exports: [
    HeaderPage
 ]
})
export class HeaderPageModule {}
```

Comment: if you are doing like this. make component not page. 
`ionic g compoment header` like this.

Comment: can you try import HeaderPageModule and not HeaderPage in your home module?

Comment: Yes, this was the missing step. I changed the Header to be a component and now it works. 
You've made a person happy today. 
Thank you. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make this happen, follow the following steps

1. Create a Module called `SharedModule` with the command `ionic generate module shared`
2. Import the `SharedModule` in the imports' array of your `app.module.ts`
3. Add your Header and Footer components in the declarations' and exports' array of your `shared.module.ts`
4. Next add `SharedModule` in the imports' array of your `home.module.ts`
5. If ionic tags are not recognized by the compiler in the component you are trying to share, import 'IonicModule' from '@ionic/angular' in the imports array of the shared.module.ts.

This way, when you need to add `<app-header>` on a new page, just repeat step 4 by adding it to the module of the new page.

When you need to add a new component that can be used globally, just repeat step 3 by adding the component to the SharedModule declarations and export.

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: It works. I modified the Header (which was a Page) to be a Component and then made everything as you said using the shared module. 
Thank you for helping.

Comment: glad to help 

Comment: its start showing `'ion-icon' is not a known element:`

Comment: @RahulSharma you can fix it by adding `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';` to imports` array of @NgModule of your SharedModule

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <h1>Welcome to Ionic.</h1>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Let me know it is working or not.

Comment: The purpose was to avoid this way of working, in order to have a more structured or cleaner code. 
Nevertheless, thank you. :)